# Strategy for Train/Test-Split on Video Sequences

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing, train-test-split

My dataset consists of 15 video sequences, each sequence showing a different movement. I want to train a CNN to detect poses (e.g. standing, sitting, ...) on single frames of this dataset but struggle to decide for the best train/validate/test-split strategy. The classifier is based on single frames, so the sequencial order does not matter. Two proposals:

1. I randomly mix all frames and choose 60/20/20 for train/test/val. **Problem:** Sequence 1 most likely is in the training and the the test/validate split.
2. I choose 11/2/2 full sequences and use for train/test/val. **Problem:** Movements of the test/val sequences are not in the training split. The CNN might miss important information.

What do you guys think is the best option here, any suggestion appreciated.

PS: Please do not nail me down on the percentages or the number of sequences chosen.